# Hide and Show Div with button

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

guys, I'm trying something for my portfolio but I'm stuck and my brain just can't understand what I'm supposed to do can you guys please help?

So I have a div section that I'm hiding, then with a BUTTON(More) click it is supposed to show the div, and the BUTTON(More) should change to BUTTON(LESS). And I really want to make it work the way I'm doing it because I know it can work I'm just not too sure how. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVYfj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5BSp.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HTMLelement.addEventListener` to handle button click event and hide or show the div appropriately using the `element.style.display` property, the code below demonstrates how it works

```js
const divE = document.getElementById('more');
const btn = document.getElementById('show');


handler = () => {
    if (divE.style.display != 'none') {
        // if the element is not hidden, hide the element and change button text to "more"
        btn.innerHTML = 'More';
        divE.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        // if the element is hidden, show the element and change button text to "less"
        btn.innerHTML = 'Less';
        divE.style.display = 'block'
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', handler)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="show">Less</button>
    <div id="more">
        IDk something here ig
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi so for some reason its not toggling the hide and show on the btn it unhides but then if i click the btn agian to hide it it does not do so?

Comment: i just checked again run my snippet, it worked for me

Comment: Ye i see yours works but for me i don't know why and im not getting errors let me post it here, how do i show you a screenshot?

Comment: in your code you're not actually toggling anything, you're just logging messages

Comment: replace your javascript file with mine, and replace the `getElementById` parameters with your element IDs

Comment: Will do that now.

Comment: Good demo. You might consider a couple of optimizations for similar future answers. You might show an OP how to get the clicked element in a listener by using [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (instead of using an outer-scope identifier like `divE`). And to demonstrate the best practice of letting CSS handle formatting, you might add/remove a class (like [`divE.classList.toggle('hidden')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), instead of accessing the style property manually), with CSS like `.hidden{ display: none; }`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, ill keep this in mind, dunno why i got a negative vote though

Comment: Me neither. I think it would be cool if Stack Overflow required initial negative votes to be accompanied by comments so posters would get more useful feedback when folks dislike their posts. (I added an upvote to get the answer out of the negatives.)

Comment: @Cat tysm :) have a great one man